# Progress bar in BackgroundDownloader (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, progress-bar

I am using BackgroundDownloader for download a file from URL. I have to display each download percentage (like 1%,2%,3%,...) in progress bar and display as text. But I am getting bunch of download percentage (like 40%, 60%...) for every download(only one file). Here is my code:

```
private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri source;
        StorageFile destinationFile;
        StorageFolder folder;
        string destination = "SampleImage.png";
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(txtUrl.Text.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out source))
        {
            txtUrl.Text = "Pls provide correct URL...";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("SampleFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            destinationFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        }
        catch
        {
            txtProgress.Text = "Opss something went wrong... try again....";
            return;
        }

        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

        if (download != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback); // for showing progress
                await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cancelProcess.Token, progress);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                txtProgress.Text = "Canceled";
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                txtProgress.Text = "Something went wrong pls try again....";
            }
        }
    }
//for showing progress
private void ProgressCallback(DownloadOperation obj)
    {
        double progress = 0;
        if (obj.Progress.BytesReceived > 0)
        {
            progress = obj.Progress.BytesReceived * 100 / obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
            if (progress > 0)
            {
                txtProgress.Text = string.Format("Downloading your file.... {0}%", progress);
                pbDownloading.Value = progress; // passing progress bar value
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtProgress.Text = "Check your internet connection...";
        }
    }
```

How can I get each and every progress % of download with this...? or any other best way to do this...?

Comment: So what the problem, all downloads use same txtProgress and swapping text in it like mad?

Comment: @alxx i am getting this for single file download.. not for more than 1 file... and txtProgress is a textblock not textbox.

Comment: So what's the problem again? I see hardcoded id (txtProgress) in your progress handler. If this handler is used multiple times, textbox will flicker with different progresses.

Comment: problem is, i need to control the TotalBytesToReceive for downloader. downloader have to work with same byte which was i set...

Comment: ...Sorry, I stopped to understand you entirely. What do you want to accomplish, in details?

Comment: really sorry for the poor explanation.. simply, i need trigger the Progressbar value for each byte the BackgroundDownloader receives on downloading a single file from url.

Comment: So it must go through every possible value (41%, 42%, 43%...) instead of jumpy behavior (40%, 50%), even if file is downloaded in ten-percent parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need *smooth* change of download progress (measured in integer percents) instead of possibly jumpy. Then you should not display raw download progress as it is, but create method that increments displayed progress by 1% (`nextPercent`) and call it with some frequency proportional to download speed.

First, you need to set timer to check download state. Timer frequency can be about 10 ticks per second, this is how fast download progress can be updated. Download handler should update internal variable `int DownloadPercent` and measure download speed in percents per millisecond: `double DownloadSpeed = DownloadPercent/(DateTime.Now - DownloadStartTime).TotalMilliseconds;`
Then DispatcherTimer callback will check download progress 10 times per second and call nextPercent if displayed progress is less than actual AND sufficient time has passed since last UI update. Now, how do you determine what sufficient time is:

```
DateTime lastUIUpdate; //class variable, initialized when download starts and UI is set to 0%
int DisplayedPercent;

void nextPercent(object sender, object args) {
    if (DisplayedPercent == DownloadPercent) return;

    double uiUpdateSpeed = (DateTime.Now - lastUIUpdate).TotalMilliseconds / (DisplayedPercent + 1);
    if (uiUpdateSpeed < DownloadSpeed) {
         nextPercent();
    }
}
```

I'm sure this will require some tuning, but you should get the idea. Good luck!